# Matrix singular value decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, orthogonality, cross-product

For a $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$, the singular value decomposition is $A = USV^T$. For $U = [u_1 u_2 u_3]$, I'm attempting to understand why the dot product of the cross product of $u1$ and $u_2$, $u_3$ is always $1$. In otherwords, `dot(cross(u1,u2), u3) = 1.`

I understand that $1$ comes from the cosine in the definition of the dot product, but I'm unable to have an intuitive understanding beyond that.

Comment: It isn't always $1$, but always $\pm1$. Note that $(u_1\times u_2)\cdot u_3$ is identical to $\det(u_1,u_2,u_3)=\det(U)$, which is equal to $\pm1$ because $U$ is an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: Geometrically $u_1,u_2$ and $u_3$ are three mutually orthogonal unit vectors. Therefore $u_1\times u_2=\pm u_3$. In turn, $(u_1\times u_2)\cdot u_3=\pm1$.